# The RMI compiler cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, rmi

I have installed the latest java JDK jdk1.7.0_17 and i am creating an RMI application on eclipse juno, RMI plugin tells me there is no RMI compiler so it cannot generate stubs. Is there a specific JDK i should download?

Comment: Have you take a look at http://www.genady.net/rmi/v20/docs/builder/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me, in eclipse under installed jre the path was pointing to jre instead of jdk.made the change and vualar.. Thanks

Comment: Groovy , I'll post it then as an answer

Comment: ****SOLVED***** Thanks you do that very fast. heheh..